# Definition of linear connection with subscription i,j

Tags: differential-geometry, notation, tensors, trace, connections

the formula
$$ trace\nabla du = \sum_i \nabla du (e_i,e_i) = (g^{ij}\nabla_i\nabla_ju^k) \dfrac{\partial}{\partial x^k} $$

what do $\nabla_i,\nabla_j$ mean? where can I find the detailed description of this symbol? Is there anything like $\nabla^i,\nabla^j$?

Comment: This often depends on the author of the text you are reading, but typically,
in a coordinate system $x$, $$\nabla_i := \nabla_{\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}}$$ Sometimes poeple are using $$\nabla^i := g^{ik}\nabla_k$$ (summation convention is assumed).

Comment: Those look like the [covariant derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariant_derivative).